# C# AT Command information to text box

Tags: c#, at-command

i want to ask how to send at command information to text box?

My code is

```
serialPort1.Open();

//manuf
serialPort1.Write("AT+CGMI" + System.Environment.NewLine);
//Thread.Sleep(1000);
txtmanuf.text=serialport1.ReadTo("AT+CGMI").ToString();

//TYPE MODEM
serialPort1.Write("AT+CGMM" + System.Environment.NewLine);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
txtType.Text= serialPort1.ReadExisting().ToString();

//IMEI
serialPort1.Write("AT+CGSN" + System.Environment.NewLine);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
txtimei.text=serialport1.ReadTo("AT+CGSN").ToString();

//phone number
serialPort1.Write("AT+CNUM" + System.Environment.NewLine);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
txtphone.text=serialport1.ReadTo("AT+CNUM").ToString();
```

If I use ReadExisting() all information entered into one text box , and if I use ReadTo("AT+..") there are no errors but when I run the program and click my button my program directly close

Comment: Do you use a `try{} catch{}` block? 'Directly close' sounds like an unhandled execption with a debugger not configured to stop at this specific exception to me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that your Eventhandler is on a different thread than your ui thread. You need to call Invoke on the textbox to set your text.

```
textbox.Invoke(()=>{textbox.Text=serialport.ReadExisting().ToString();});
```

Maybe the Invoke is called a little different. I can't test it currently.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not handling your exception that's why it closes however if ReadExisting() is working for you then try this

```
string data=Process(serialPort1.readExisting(),"AT+..");
```

and the code for Process is following

```
private string Process(string input,string rto)
{
   int location=input.indexOf(rto);
   string temp=null;
   char[] array=input.toCharArray();
   for(int i=0;i<location;i++)
   {
      temp+=array[i];
   }
   temp=temp.Remove(location,rto.Length);
   serialPort1.DiscardInBuffer();
  return temp;
}
```

According to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readto(v=vs.110).aspx) readto just read the buffer to the specified string and specified string is not included it is removed from the buffer so its the alternative of readto try this

Comment: thks sir, i'm already try i get error informations "System.NullReferenceException occured in projext.exe additional info: object reference not set to an intance of an project" ReadExiting() is good not have error but i get all information in one text box if I use that, i want just show my modem model in txtType

Comment: try to initiate your serialPort1 object that's why its giving NullRefrencexception

Comment: like this serialPort1.DiscardNull = true; ?

Comment: like this serialPort1=new SerialPort(); and then set other properties like comport baudrate and timeouts etc